# Does the space of matrices above rank $k$ admit a transitive Lie group action?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, group-actions, matrix-rank, homogeneous-spaces

$\newcommand{\End}{\operatorname{End}}$
$\newcommand{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}$

Let $V$ be a **real** $d$-dimensional vector space ($d \ge 4$). Let $2 \le k \le d-2$.
Define $H_{>k}=\{ A \in \text{End}(V) \mid \operatorname{rank}(A) > k 
\}$. $H_{>k}$ is an open connected submanifold of $ \text{End}(V)$.

> **Question:** Does $H_{>k}$ admit a **transitive Lie group action**?

That is, does there exist a (finite dimeniosnal) Lie group $G$, and a smooth action of $G$ on $H_{>k}$, such that $H_{>k}$ itself is the single orbit?

---

There is a natural action on $H_{>k}$ by $\GL(V) \times \GL(V)$, given by
$$
(A,B) \cdot C=ACB^{-1}.
$$

This action has a **finite** number of orbits; each orbit is the space of endomorphisms of a certain rank. So, it is not transitive. (but is "close" to being one).

Even if there is a transitive action, I don't expect it to be as "natural" as the action considered above. Still, I am interested to know whether or not such group action exist.

I know there are obstructions for a manifold to admit a transitive Lie group action in the case where it's compact. Here, however, our manifold $H_{>k}$ is non-compact.